# Adding a breakpoint in Eclipse, causes Dalvik to crash

Tags: android, eclipse, dalvik, breakpoints

This is an interesting bug of Eclipse. I am using:

**Version:** Indigo Release
**Build id:** 20110615-0604

Out of nowhere today, I set a breakpoint in my android app on Eclipse. When it reaches the code, debug (dalvik JVM) aborts and crashes:

> Tried to execute code in unprepared class (followed by the class name)

If I don't set the break point, it will run through with no problem. I have searched through Google but found nothing so far.

Another note, where I set this breakpoint does not matter, it could simply be the 1st line of onClick() function, or anywhere else. The moment the app "**pauses**" due to the breakpoint, it crashes.

Comment: Sounds like a real strange bug. 
My suggestion: restart eclipse, restart computer if still not working reinstall eclipse and sdk.
Do you debug on emulator on device?

Comment: I debug on my phone. I did clean project, restart eclipse, not my computer though. I copied the same code to my office, then it had no problem with break points or anything. Weird bug and so little information about this error message.

Comment: For future user: This also happens in Eclipse Kepler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by removing an unused import package.

actually the error message is saying "tried to execute code in unprepared class" (followed by the class name)

I am not using that class but it is imported.

Simply remove the import, and it works fine ....

Comment: Not work I removed all unused, and get the same error

Answer (score 26):

I run into the same issue; for me, the problem was solved by removing all of the watched expressions I had set up in the debugger (one of them was causing the problem).

Comment: I had a similar error with `ERROR: tried to execute code in unprepared class 'Landroid/nfc/tech/IsoDep;' (5)` message and sorted it out removing all watched expressions too.

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same issue when used watch expression with static method of this (unprepared) class.
I solved this issue by removing this expression from expressions list.

Comment: Same case here, I did not remove all watch expressions, just the one of the static method of the "unprepared class". Eclipse version: Indigo 3.7.1.

Comment: yep! I have the exact problem with static method in the watch expression. Thanks!